# pfsense: No more processes

Tags: firewall, pfsense

Sometimes my pfsense (1.2.3-RELEASE) goes crazy:

- every nat rules go down
- the web interface reply me with many errors (Warning: shell_exec(): Unable to execute...)
- my ssh daemon refuse to open a new session.

All other traffic types go good.

If I have a ssh session before that the error appear, for every command
that i run in that ssh session I receive:
*No more processes*

I resolve the situation with an hard reset.

The only strange thing that i have notice, is some illegal attempts on my 
ssh port. But it seems that no one has gained access.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the same problem because a cron job was running every minute but was not finishing. This created hundreds of processes each running in a shell exhausting the system.

So check using `ps ax` if you see a lot of duplicate processes maybe check your cron jobs or anything else that might be spinning up a bunch of extra shells.